# How to unquote in GIMP Scheme

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I never used any other implementations than GIMP's script-fu, and I am even quite new to GIMP's Scheme, too. So, maybe I'm wrong. However, the followings do not work in Script-Fu console:

```
(define x 13)
(define s 'x) ; or (define s `x)
,s => Error: eval: unbound variable: unquote
```

similarly

```
(unquote s) => Error: eval: unbound variable: unquote
```

It seems to me, that "," was planned to work but unquote has not been implemented.
If so, how can I solve the following problem?

```
(define x 13)
(define y 7)
; define procedure to swap x and y
(define (swap) 
  (let ((t 0))
    (set! t ,'x)
    (set! x ,'y)
    (set! y t)
  )
)
```

This should run multiple times, so *(set! t x)...* will not work.

Comment: `unquote` doesn't work the way you think it does, in any implementation, ever. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "`(set! t x)` will not work".

Comment: In particular, [`unquote` is not `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18515295/13), and you shouldn't use `eval` for this, either.

Comment: I tried `(set! t x)` first, but it did not work. It swapped the values just once and never again. I thought values x and y have been evaluated in "define-time". Now I tried it again, and works. I do not know, what I made wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `swap` function will work as:

```
(define (swap)
  (let ((t 0))
    (set! t x)
    (set! x y)
    (set! y t)))
```

because `set!` is a syntactic keyword that evaluates its arguments specially.  The first argument (`t` in the first `set!` expression in `swap` above) is not evaluated; rather it is used to identify a location.  The second argument (`x`) is evaluated and, in this case, returns the value held in the location referenced by the identifier (`x`).

The syntactic keyword `define` works similarly.  The first argument is not evaluated; it is used to create a new location; the second argument is evaluated.  So, for your example, `unquote` is not needed just use:

```
(define s x)
```

If you are trying to define `s` so it returns the current value of `x` rather then the value bound to `x` when `s` is allocated, then make `s` a function:

```
(define (s) x)
```

Then the expression `(s)` will return whatever `x` is currently bound to.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it did not work (that is what I wrote in my post). It swapped the values just once and never again. I thought values x and y have been evaluated in "define-time". Now I tried it again, and works. I do not know, what I made wrong. Thanks.